# How can i optimize this recursive method

Tags: c#, optimization, recursion

I'm trying to make a word puzzle game, and for that i'm using a recursive method to find all possible words in the given letters.
The letters is in a 4x4 board.

Like this:

```
ABCD
EFGH
HIJK
LMNO
```

The recursive method is called inside this loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
            {
                myScabble.Search(letters, y, x, width, height, "", covered, t);
            }
        }
```

letters is a 2D array of chars.

y & x is ints that shows where in the board

width & height is also int, that tells the dimensions of the board

"" is the string we are trying to make (the word)

covered is an array of bools, to check if we allready used that square.

t is a List (wich contains all the words to check against).

The recursive method that need optimizing:

```
public void Search(char[,] letters, int y, int x, int width, int height, string build, bool[,] covered, List<aWord> tt)
    {
        // Dont get outside the bounds
        if (y >= width || y < 0 || x >= height || x < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Dont deal with allrady covered squares
        if (covered[x, y])
        {
            return;
        }

        // Get Letter
        char letter = letters[x, y];

        // Append
        string pass = build + letter;

        // check if its a possibel word
        //List<aWord> t = myWords.aWord.Where(w => w.word.StartsWith(pass)).ToList();
        List<aWord> t = tt.Where(w => w.word.StartsWith(pass)).ToList();
        // check if the list is emphty
        if (t.Count < 10 && t.Count != 0)
        {
            //stop point
        }
        if (t.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        // Check if its a complete word.
        if (t[0].word == pass)
        {
            //check if its allrdy present in the _found dictinary

            if (!_found.ContainsKey(pass))
            {
                //if not add the word to the dictionary
                _found.Add(pass, true);
            }

        }
        // Check to see if there is more than 1 more that matches string pass 
        // ie. are there more words to find.
        if (t.Count > 1)
        {
            // make a copy of the covered array
            bool[,] cov = new bool[height, width];
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < height; a++)
                {
                    cov[a, i] = covered[a, i];
                }
            }
            // Set the current square as covered.
            cov[x, y] = true;

            // Continue in all 8 directions.
            Search(letters, y + 1, x, width, height, pass, cov, t);
            Search(letters, y, x + 1, width, height, pass, cov, t);
            Search(letters, y + 1, x + 1, width, height, pass, cov, t);
            Search(letters, y - 1, x, width, height, pass, cov, t);
            Search(letters, y, x - 1, width, height, pass, cov, t);
            Search(letters, y - 1, x - 1, width, height, pass, cov, t);
            Search(letters, y - 1, x + 1, width, height, pass, cov, t);
            Search(letters, y + 1, x - 1, width, height, pass, cov, t);

        }


    }
```

The code works as i expected it to do, however it is very slow.. it takes about 2 mins to find the words.

> EDIT: i clarified that the letters
>   array is 2D

I wanna show how i got the algorithm to work really fast.
i used @Enigmativity 's implementation of a Trie, with the search pattern described by @EricLippert

```
public void SearchWord(char[,] letters, Trie parentTrie, char[] build, int x, int y, bool[,] covered )
    {
        char[] pass = new char[build.Length + 1];
        build.CopyTo(pass, 0);

        // iterate through all squares in the board.
        for (var r = 0; r < letters.GetLength(0); r++ )
        {
            for (var c = 0; c < letters.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                //check if this square is naighbor to the last square
                if ((IsNeighbor(x, y, r, c)|| x == -1) && !(covered[r, c]))
                {
                    // check if the current Trie contains the letter
                    if (parentTrie.ContainsKey(letters[r,c]))
                    {
                        pass[build.Length] = letters[r, c];
                        covered[r, c] = true;
                        SearchWord(letters, parentTrie[letters[r, c]], pass, r, c, covered);
                        covered[r, c] = false;
                    }
                    if (parentTrie.ContainsKey('$') && (!myStrings.Contains(new string(build).ToLower())))
                        myStrings.Add(new string(build).ToLower());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It is initially called by this :

```
SearchWord(letters, trie, new char[0], -1, -1, new bool[letters.GetLength(0), letters.GetLength(1)]);
```

i realize that i could add letters as a property, but since its a reference type it is not very time expensive

Comment: Do you have profiling output for this code?  Is the `StartsWith`, copying, and all of that slow?  You might want to just optimize that part, probably using a faster data structure (like a binary tree, or even better a trie) for `tt`.

Comment: You also don't need to copy `covered` into `cov`.  Do `covered[x, y] = true` before the recursive calls and then `covered[x, y] = false` afterward, then pass `covered` itself into the recursions.

Comment: Also, are strings slow to append (when a `StringBuilder` equivalent isn't used)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The other answers are right: you should abandon this algorithm entirely and start over.

The way to deal with these problems in word games is to transform the dictionary into a form that is amenable to the kinds of searches you want to do. In your case, the data structure you want to build is called a **trie**, which is a pun because it is a "tree" that does fast "re-trie-val", ha ha ha, those computer science guys are very witty!

The way a trie works is you have a tree where every node has up to 27 children. Suppose you have the dictionary { AB, ACE, ACT, CAT }. The trie looks like this:

```
         root
      /        \
     A          C
    / \         |
   B   C        A
   |  / \       |
   $ E   T      T
     |   |      |
     $   $      $
```

where $ means "the word is ended". Every path from the root to a $ is a legal word.

Now to find all the words, first build the trie out of the dictionary. Then for each starting point in the grid, try every possible word in the trie. If you start with a grid square that contains an A then of course you do not traverse down the C branch of the trie. Then for each child of the A in the trie, see if the grid has a neighbouring square that can drive you deeper into the trie.

That's the interesting recursive algorithm, and you'll find that it is very fast because you can be very smart about abandoning huge numbers of words that can't possibly exist starting from a given square.

Does that all make sense?

Comment: This certainly makes sense, but for a dictionary as large as say the English Scrabble dictionary, a trie is pretty memory-hungry. Personally I wrote myself an algorithm that generates a minimal [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAWG), which is smaller memory-wise, and the search algorithm is pretty much exactly the same, but now the problem is that generating it takes long (≈2 minutes), so I had to serialize the resulting graph into a file and have the game just load the file.

Comment: im at the moment using @Enigmativity Trie implementation, (wich is a bit slow to low on start).. other that that im using the recursive algorithm @EricLibbert descrips here.... See the Original question for the code.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably more efficient to attack this in the opposite direction.  Iterate over you list of possible words,  look for the first letter of the word in the grid, if you find it look for the second in adjacent square, if you find it keep trying to match further along that line.

This way you can quickly eliminate words entirely rather than repeatedly check for every word in every possible position.

Just looking at the code you are using in something that is going to repeat thousands of times LINQ is probably a no-no.  You are using string manipulation, so you are generating thousands of strings in memory, and possibly causing the garbage collector to run during the recursion, you should switch to string builder or some sort of character array.

There are loads of optimisations you can do at this point, for example do a quick first pass on your list checking that every letter of each word is somewhere in the grid (just put all letters in the grid into a string to make this easy), then you can quickly eliminate words where not all their letters are in the grid - before even worrying about if they are in the right order.

You could turn your grid into a series of strings, each representing a certain orientation of the grid and then just use plain string searches.  If you find a match you would just need to make sure the match wasn't across the boundary of the grid which can be done by checking the start and end point of the match quite quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Make the invariant arguments (letter, width, height and tt) fields.  Do not use Linq, it is slow over many iterations.  Also, change your list of words to a more effecient Dictionary or some type of sorted list.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I might put forward code based on Eric Lippert's answer. Eric nailed it, but hard code is always better. ;-)

To start with, here is a simple implementation of a trie:

```
public class Trie : Dictionary<char, Trie>
{
    public int Frequency { get; set; }

    public void Add(IEnumerable<char> chars)
    {
        if (chars == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException("chars");
        if (chars.Any())
        {
            var head = chars.First();
            if (!this.ContainsKey(head))
            {
                this.Add(head, new Trie());
            }
            var tail = this.GetSafeTail(head, chars.Skip(1));
            if (tail.Any())
            {
                this[head].Add(tail);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(IEnumerable<char> chars)
    {
        if (chars == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException("chars");
        var @return = false;
        if (chars.Any())
        {
            var head = chars.First();
            if (this.ContainsKey(head))
            {
                var tail = this.GetSafeTail(head, chars.Skip(1));
                @return = tail.Any() ? this[head].Contains(tail) : true;
            }
        }
        return @return;
    }

    private IEnumerable<char> GetSafeTail(char head, IEnumerable<char> tail)
    {
        return ((!tail.Any()) && (head != '$')) ? new [] { '$', } : tail;
    }
}
```

This code allows you to pass strings to the `Add` & `Contains` methods as strings are `IEnumerable<char>`.

It can be used like so:

```
var trie = new Trie();
var before = trie.Contains("Hello"); // == false
trie.Add("Hello");
var after = trie.Contains("Hello"); // == true
```

Now, given a grid of letters and a trie loaded up with the possible words I can run the following query to get the matches:

```
var matches =
    from w in this.GetPossibleWords(letters)
    where trie.Contains(w)
    select w;
```

The `GetPossibleWords` method is implemented as such:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPossibleWords(char[,] letters)
{
    return
        from ws in this.GetPossibleWordLists(letters)
        from w in ws
        select w;
}

private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetPossibleWordLists(char[,] letters)
{
    Func<int, int> inc = x => x + 1;
    Func<int, int> nop = x => x;
    Func<int, int> dec = x => x - 1;
    for (var r = letters.GetLowerBound(0);
        r <= letters.GetUpperBound(0); r++)
    {
        for (var c = letters.GetLowerBound(1);
            c <= letters.GetUpperBound(1); c++)
        {
            yield return new [] { letters[r, c].ToString(), };
            yield return this.GetPossibleWords(letters, r, c, dec, dec);
            yield return this.GetPossibleWords(letters, r, c, inc, dec);
            yield return this.GetPossibleWords(letters, r, c, nop, dec);
            yield return this.GetPossibleWords(letters, r, c, dec, nop);
            yield return this.GetPossibleWords(letters, r, c, inc, nop);
            yield return this.GetPossibleWords(letters, r, c, nop, inc);
            yield return this.GetPossibleWords(letters, r, c, dec, inc);
            yield return this.GetPossibleWords(letters, r, c, inc, inc);
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetPossibleWords(char[,] letters,
    int r, int c,
    Func<int, int> rd, Func<int, int> cd)
{
    var chars = new List<char>();
    while (r >= letters.GetLowerBound(0) && r <= letters.GetUpperBound(0)
        && c >= letters.GetLowerBound(1) && c <= letters.GetUpperBound(1))
    {
        chars.Add(letters[r, c]);
        if (chars.Count > 1)
        {
            yield return new string(chars.ToArray());
        }
        r = rd(r);
        c = cd(c);
    }
}
```

The performance of this solution seems quite good.

The OP had a 4x4 grid taking roughly 120 seconds (2 mins). My code can match a list of 208,560 words in a 40x40 grid in 20.3 seconds.

Not bad, huh?

Thanks again to Eric for the idea of using a trie.

Comment: hmm, the initial load of the Trie into memoray takes about 40 sec.. but im thinking that its because i load it from me originally sqlCe database, wich is kinda slow .. maybee i can serialize it to xml the trie structure sounds like somthing perfect for xml.

Comment: There is something worng with the GetPossibleWords method tho... it doesn't find all possible words, i can find more (and yes i checked to see if the word was actually in the original Database)

Comment: ... I just realized that Trie implements IDictionary, so it cannot be XMLserialized...

Comment: @Tirdyr - When I tested my code I found that loading the trie took about the same time as checking for the words. This was probably a bit of a co-incidence, but I did load and search for the same number of words. I loaded over 200,000 words in around 20 seconds, so 10,000 words per second. How many words are you loading from the database?

Comment: @Enigmativity - My original Database is aprox 350.000 words so that consists fine with 10.000 words per sec.

Comment: @Tirdyr - My trie implementation isn't as efficient as it could be. I inherited from `Dictionary<,>` for convenience, but it is slow to load. Using an array of characters would be faster, but you'd need to check array bounds, etc.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I can live with the 36 secs, initial load of the trie - i might work on that later on.. but i cant get the GetPossibleWords method to work.. it only finds some of the words.

Comment: running some test runs, i find that GetPossibleWords only returns a "list" of 167 possible words. none of wich are more than 4 char long. and it looks like the function only travels in straight lines from the start point. ie. up or down or left or right, or NE (upright), NW, SE, SW.

Comment: @Tirdyr - I was working under the assumption that you were looking for linear words. I didn't pay close enough attention to your `Search` method. I'll have a bit of a think...

Answer (score 2):

One optimization would be in your directional search. You only need to search down, left, and down-left diagonally as searching up, right, and up-right diagonally will give you the same result as simply reversing the string.

[image: Grid search graphic]

EDIT:

Of interest also might be [Project Euler Problem #11](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=11) and a writeup of a solution using C# and LINQ [here](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/05/project-euler-problem-11.html).

This is a completely untested example of what I was trying to describe.

```
    static List<string> Solve()
{
    // Declaring a empty list of strings to hold our results up front.
    List<string> words = new List<string>();

    // I'm using set as the term for your grid of letters.
    string set = @"ABCD
                   EFGH
                   HIJK
                   LMNO";

    // i'm explicitly defining the dimensions, you need to figure this out.
    int sizeX = 4;
    int sizeY = 4;

    // i'm also specifying a maximum word length. you might find a word like 
    // supercalifragilisticexpialidocious, but i doubt it so lets not waste time.
    int maximumWordSize = 3;

    // first, our trie/wordlist/etc. assume `GetWordList()` gets a list of all
    // valid words with indicated number of characters.
    List<string> wordList = GetWordList(3);

    // second, we load a character array with the set.
    char[,] data = new char[sizeX, sizeY];
    string[] lines = set.Split('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Count() -1; i++)
    {
        string line = lines[i].Trim();
        for (int j = 0; j <= line.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            char[j,i] = lines[j];
        }
    }

    // third, we iterate over the data
    for(int x = 0; x <= sizeX - maximumWordSize; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= sizeY - maximumWordSize; y++)
        {
            // check to see if we even have any words starting with our cursor
            var validWords = wordList.Where(w=>w.Contains(data[x,y]));
            if (validWords.Count() > 0)
            {
                // ok, we have words. continue on our quest!
                // (this is where your initial qualifier changes if you use a trie
                // or other search method)

                char[] characters = char[maximumWordSize];

                // search left
                for (int i = x; i <= x + maximumWordSize - 1; i++)
                    characters[i] = data[i, y];
                words.AddRange(Search(characters, wordList));

                // search down
                for (int i = y + maximumWordSize - 1; i <= y; i--)
                    characters[i] = data[x, y];
                words.AddRange(Search(characters, wordList));

                // search diagonal right
                for (int i = x; i <= x + maximumWordSize - 1; i++)
                    for (int j = y + maximumWordSize - 1; j <= y; j--)
                        characters[i] = data[i, j];
                words.AddRange(Search(characters, wordList));

                // search diagonal left
                for (int i = x; i <= x - MaximumWordSize + 1; i++)
                    for (int j = y + maximumWordSize - 1; j <= y; j--)
                        characters[i] = data[i, j];
                words.AddRange(Search(characters, wordList));
            }
        }
    }

    return words;
}

static List<string> Search(char[] Input, List<string> WordList)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    string word = "";
    // find forwards
    for (int i = 0; i <= Input.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        word += Input[i];
        if (WordList.Contains(word))
            result.Add(word);
    }

    // find backwards
    Array.Reverse(Input);
    for (int i = 0; i <= Input.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        word += Input[i];
        if (WordList.Contains(word))
            result.Add(word);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: this i dont understand.. are you sure this is true.. (also considering that you left a direction out up-left(or down-right), i cant see how i can search from one of the middel letters in this fashion and be sure to get alle possible words.

Comment: but then what about a word created [0,0]-[0,1]-[1,1]-[1,2]-[0,1] (afghc) in the above example.

Comment: i see. your search is more in the vein of boggle than a simple word find.

Comment: This last edit you made actually made the biggest optimizazion to me algorithm.. i realized that even tho there might be words at 16 letters, and they might even exist ind the word grid.. noone would ever find them.. there for by adding in a maximum length of 8 letters to both my Trie, and my word list, i really won alot of time

Answer (score 2):

1. **Use better prepared data structures**. Instead of using `List` to store all the words use some tree-like structure. Or at least a sorted list + binary search. This point should improve performance dramatically. I would recommend using ordered collection and passing range indices through recursice methods. I.e. you will look for first letter and determine that words starting with that letter have 123-456 indices. Next time you append new letter you will make this range even more narrow and you won't need to go through entire collection!
2. **Prefilter your words collection**. You have only 16 letters, it means that more than 10 letters are missing. You can filter your words collection and remove all the words which have missing numbers.
3. **Lazy LINQ**. If you want to use Linq then don't force to iterate through the entire collection (I mean do not call `ToList` method). You can use it's lazy nature to iterate only until you need since you do not care how many words start with this subword if this number is more than 2.
4. **Do not copy cov**. Instead of copying an entire array every time simply set `cov[x, y] = true;` and after nested search tries put back `false` value: `cov[x, y] = false;`
5. **Use profiler**. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another optimization would be data structures:

```
List<aWord> t = tt.Where(w => w.word.StartsWith(pass)).ToList();
```

This is O(n) over all valid words, you could improve the performance by using i.e. a trie.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# too well, but here's how I would do it in C++ (some things are pseudocode to make it easier to read); it should be easy to translate:

```
struct word_search {
  const set<string>& words; // This is a balanced search tree
  const vector<vector<char> >& letters;
  const int width, height;
  vector<vector<bool> > marks;
  string word_so_far;

  // Add constructor
  void search(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height || marks[x][y]) return;
    word_so_far += letters[x][y];
    set<string>::const_iterator it = words.lower_bound(word_so_far);
    if (it == words.end() ||
        it->substr(0, word_so_far.size()) != word_so_far) {
      word_so_far.resize(word_so_far.size() - 1);
      return;
    }
    marks[x][y] = true;
    for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; ++dx)
      for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; ++dy)
        search(x + dx, y + dy);
    marks[x][y] = false;
    word_so_far.resize(word_so_far.size() - 1);
  }
};
```

In C#, `set<string>` would be `SortedSet`, and the `vector<vector<...> >` types would be 2-D arrays.  I am not sure of the equivalent to `lower_bound`, though; `SortedSet` doesn't seem to have anything like it.